# loopback: get access token on container when user upload file

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I'm trying to get the user details by his access token on Container model of loopback 3 with node.js, when the user uploads their files.

I tried this code on model:

```
Container.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, unused, next) {
    console.log("token", context.req.accessToken.userId);
    next();
)}
```

But I got undefined.
How can I get the access token of user on container model?

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you need token
var token = ctx.req.query.access_token;

//if you need userID by token
var AccessToken = app.models['accessToken'];

AccessToken.findForRequest(req, {}, function (err, token) {            
    var userID = token.userId;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get User detail By: EndUser(Your user model)

```
const user = ctx.Model.app.models.EndUser;
 const userId = ctx.req.accessToken.userId
 EndUser.findById(userId, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
            logger.error("ERROR WHILE GETTING USER > ", error);
            cb(error);
            return;
        }
        if (!user) {
            cb({
                statusCode: 404,
                message: "User Not Found"
            });
            return;
        }
        user = user.toJSON();
        console.log(user)
  });
```